# How to insert to database using silverlight Dataset

Tags: database, silverlight

How can I enter dataset into the database using data
An example please

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a database directly from a Silverlight client.  There are several ways to accomplish this but you basically need to call a web service from Silverlight.  See the following article for a step by step example: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197937(VS.95).aspx